# Use @ionic-native/http in Ionic 4 Application

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, module

I'm trying to use the `@ionic-native/http` module inside my Ionic 4 app. It's fresh new and trying to use it in the home.page component. But I get this error : [image: error]

`Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'HTTP' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.`

I tried many things, even using the `@beta` module,
I added the import statement in the `app.module.ts` and in the imports [] array.

Her is the app.module.ts

```js
...

import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, HTTP],
...
```

And here is the home.page.ts file

```js
...
  import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
  })

  export class HomePage {
    constructor(private http: HTTP) {}
....
  }
```

What am I missing ?

Have a nice evening everyone.

Comment: Why u r using `ngx` in plugin path ?

Comment: From this post : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/15199

Comment: Have you tried without `ngx` ? as it will work for all my apps so.

Comment: you can install using :: npm install --save @ionic-native/http   for fix this..  in my case i fixed this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP is not a module. You have to put it under your app modules provider array.

```
...

import { HTTP } from '@ionic-native/http/ngx';
...

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [HTTP]
...
```

for reference: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/#Add_Plugins_to_Your_App_Module